# Way to avoid creating a swift file and then copying it to the inside of my project in Xcode 7?

Tags: swift, ios9

So i'm using the Xcode 7 beta.  for example, whenever I create a new cocotouch class it always ends up being created above the project folder in the left pane of Xcode.  Until I copy it into the project, I am unable to use its functionality.  In Xcode 6, as long as I had the main storyboard tab highlighted, I could create a file that would be instantly useable.

[image]
does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I create dozens of Swift files every day and I've never seen that. If AppDelegate.swift is selected when I chose File New File, the file ends up below it and ready to go.

Comment: Right! that's what I'm used too.  However, just tried it, still having the issue.  However, I did realize that under "file", I am given options to "add ..." to my current project.  Not a fan of the extra step, but it works.

Comment: I apologize for asking, but where is the option located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new file, the last thing that happens is that you save it. It is up to you to make sure that you are saving it into the correct group inside your project navigator, and that you are adding it to the app target (checkbox):

[image]

Comment: any thoughts on why the group and target sections would be greyed out?

Comment: I've never seen that, and I can't reproduce it - I can't make them go grey. I'm tempted to suggest that your permissions are hosed. Make a new User, log in as that user, and see if you get the same issue there.

Comment: No luck creating a new user.  Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Very mysterious! Thank you for trying it; you have to admit it sounded good... At this point I'm down to suggestions like reinstalling Xcode. I have truly never seen the behavior you're describing so anything I say is just a wild guess at this point.